# Responsive image slider to fill div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-slides

I'm trying to get a responsive image slider. It musts:

- Fill the height of a div
- Overflow on width
- Be centered

It should be similar to http://www.niraalpina.com. I'm looking for a cross-browser compatible CSS solution that doesn't involve fixed dimensions.

I've uploaded the site to http://test5.twinzebras.com/, please have a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: please add some lines of code

Comment: I started working with this library yesterday: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/  It fills the width and height is auto-calculated, I'd imagine it shouldn't be too difficult to edit this to fill height not width.

Comment: Thanks MaKR, I've been trying to adapt woothemes.com/flexslider but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a setup like this:

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="img1"></div>
    <div id="img2"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#img1 {
    background: url('../img.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover; // also give 'contain' a go
}
```

If `cover` doesn't do what you want, try `contain` — I'm not quite sure which you're looking for.

Note: this solution relies on having a fixed-height div around the `.container`: This is entirely reliant on the rest of your site's setup, so we can't do much to help you there.

Comment: Thanks, have tried this with both contain and cover but nothing works when viewed in the browser.

Comment: Can you give some more information about what's not working? You will need to set a fixed height *somewhere* or the whole thing will be `height=0` and thus invisible.

Comment: j6m8 if you look at the test site you can see how the image slider is not filling the div area proportionately as it is squashing the entire width in instead of hiding it. I have set a height of:
#slides {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 1000px;

Comment: You're not using the solution I proposed, so I can't be sure what's going wrong. My best guess is that you've set `height: 100%` on each `<img>` element, which force-stretches them instead of maintaining aspect-ratio. There is no way to achieve a 'full-bleed' (no whitespace) slideshow with different-sized images in `<img>` tags, which is why I suggested the `<div>` and CSS route.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `width` and `height` to 100% in img

```css
#img1 {
    background: url('../img.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```